# How to see backslashes in string

Tags: c++, string, backslash

For a function I am making, I take a string in as a parameter and do things with it. However I treat characters in the string specially if there is a backslash before it. However I am having problems even seeing the blackslash!

```
std::string s = "01234\6";
std::cout << s << std::endl;
std::cout << s.at(5) << std::endl;
if(s.at(5)== '\\')
    std::cout << "It's a backslash" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "It's not a backslash" << std::endl;
```

outputs

```
01234

It's not a backslash
```

How am I supposed to check if mystring.at(i) == '\\' if it isn't showing up at all?

The input will be coming from another file (which I can't modify) like

```
myfunc("% \%  %");
```

If I read the string I count 3 '%' characters (so its not ignored by the backslash), and 0 '\' characters

edit: Code how I count

```
char percent = '%';
int current_index = 0;
int percent_count = 0;

int ret = str.find(percent, current_index);
while(ret != std::string::npos)
{
  percent_count++;
  current_index = ret +1;
  ret = str.find(percent, current_index);
 }

 return percent_count;
```

Comment: Is it not `s = "01234\\6";`?

Comment: `myfunc("% \%  %");` has invalid conversion specifiera so the behavior is undefined. You get what you get.

Comment: When hard-coding a string, the compiler gives special meaning to "\". And the hard-coded string will be translated into something else. Luckily (well by design), one of its special meanings is that "\\" will be treated as "\". So wherever you want a hard-coded string to contain "\", write "\\". **NOTE** That this applies to compilation only. When your program reads text from another source, it will read the text as it receives it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66912435/6327658

Answer (score 4):

C++ supports three kinds of escape sequences:

1. *simple-escape-sequence*. It is one of:

   ```
   \’ \" \? \\
   \a \b \f \n \r \t \v
   ```
2. *octal-escape-sequence*. It is one of:

   ```
   \ octal-digit
   \ octal-digit octal-digit
   \ octal-digit octal-digit octal-digit
   ```

   `\0` is the most well known octal escape sequence that represents the null character.
3. *hexadecimal-escape-sequence*. It is one of:

   ```
   \x hexadecimal-digit
   hexadecimal-escape-sequence hexadecimal-digit
   ```

When you use:

```
std::string s = "01234\6";
```

the `\6` part represents an octal escape sequence. It does not represent two characters.

It is the same as

```
std::string s = "01234?";
```

where `?` is the character represented by the octal number `6`.

In order to have `\` as an element of the string, you'll need to use:

```
std::string s = "01234\\6";
```

Comment: It's worth noting that when the input comes from a file instead of a string literal (as mentioned in the question), no escaping is needed. Backslash will be read as a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

The checking method is right, but `\` escape `6`, so `\6` is counted once, you can check `sizeof("12345\6")`, which 7, or `strlen("12345\6")`, which is 6.

Change `"12345\6"` to `"12345\\6"`.

Comment: @user2770808 don't worry. You don't really *edit* the string in a sense, you let the compiler knows that what you actually mean is to read a backslash.

Comment: @user2770808 compiler knows backslash if you read from file, which is not the same as the literal string representation in c/c++.

Answer (score 0):

The `C++` compiler would have already treated it specially if you have backslash in the string:

```
std::string s = "01234\6"; //\6 is treated differently already, as unicode character \6, not as backslash + 6
```

Unless what you mean is you want to have a text with backslash (say, from I/O). In that case, you should put `\\` to make your compiler understand that you mean it as real backslash not a unicode character:

```
std::string s = "01234\\6"; //double backslash here
```

Then you can test your program.

Comment: How come when I do myfunc("% \%  %"), I still count 3 percents? Shouldn't it only be 2 then?

Comment: Your `count` does not seem to have `if-else` distinguishing backslash. Is that full code?

Comment: I took out the if(str.at(ret-1) == '\\') because it was not working.

Comment: What I suggest would be to detect the `str` `char` one by one and if you find `\\`, then you treat your *next* character differently.

Comment: @user2770808 `\%` is `%` itself.

Comment: @delta actually it is implementation-defined (and may be unsupported entirely)

Answer (score 0):

No compiler C++ will interpret `\` as a backslash, since its the [escape character](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape). You will have to use `\\` to denote a backslash in a string.

Comment: Not quite true. You might want to broaden your horizons to other languages. ;) Or at least qualify what compilers you're describing.