# How to read a backslash as part of a string in C++

Tags: c++, escaping, string-literals, backslash, rawstring

I am trying to read a backslash as part of a string, but it is always escaped.

For example:

```
string s = "Bo\nes"

for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
    if (s[i] == '\\') cout << "Found a backslash";
}
```

That does not work.  And across other testing I always get the string reading as "Boes".  How would I be able to read that backslash such that I can parse the entire string?

Comment: This may help as well as the answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710024/what-is-a-raw-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710024/what-is-a-raw-string)

Comment: "_That does not work_" - In the future: In what way? When I read the code, I get what *I* am expecting. Please include your expected output in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Here are examples

```
std::string s1 = "Bo\\nes";
std::string s2 = R"(Bo\nes)";
```

That is either you have to use the escape sequence `'\\'` for the backslash character or a raw string literal.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::string s1 = "Bo\\nes";
    std::string s2 = R"(Bo\nes)";
    
    std::cout << "\"" << s1 << "\"\n";
    std::cout << "\"" << s2 << "\"\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
"Bo\nes"
"Bo\nes"
```

Another way is to use an octal or hexadecimal escape sequence like for example

```
std::string s = "Bo\134nes";
```

or

```
std::string s = "Bo\x5Cnes";
```

Comment: I'm given an input string (like "Bo\nes") and I need to be able to parse the character after the initial '\' (to escape it as part of the program).  Do you know if there's a way to convert a string into a raw string so I'm able to do this?

Comment: @wirly It is unclear what is the problem/ If you entered a string like this Bo\nes from a console then this expression s[i] == '\\' is correct.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working from a string being given to a class, and the input doesn't use double backslashes to escape the character

Comment: It is implementation-defined whether `'\\'` and `'\134'` (or `'\x5C'`) are equivalent.    While that is true in ANSI (or compatible) character sets, it is not true for all possible character sets.

Comment: @wirly - The escaping of a backslash is only needed in source code (in string or character literals).    If the user types `A\A`  and that is read by the program (e.g. from `std::cin`) to a `std::string` named `input` then that character will be detected using logic such as `if (input == "A\\A") ...`

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to escape the backslash in the original string.

```
string s = "Bo\\nes";
```

Otherwise, there is no backslash character in the string to compare against.

Answer (score 2):

In a string/character literal, `\n` is an [escape sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) for a line feed (decimal `10`, hex `0x0A`), and `\\` is an escape sequence for a single `\` character (decimal `92`, hex `0x5C`).

Thus, in the string literal `"Bo\nes"`, there is no `\` character in the string.  It contains these characters:

`B` `o` `\n` `e` `s` (`0x42 0x6F 0x0A 0x64 0x73`)

Not these characters, like you are expecting:

`B` `o` `\` `n` `e` `s` (`0x42 0x6F 0x5C 0x6E 0x64 0x73`)

That is why `if (s[i] == '\\')` (aka `if (s[i] == 0x5C)`) is always false.

You need to escape the `\` in `\n` to accomplish what you want:

```cpp
string s = "Bo\\nes";
```

Then the literal will contain the characters you are expecting.

Comment: what if the string s input from user?

Comment: Escape sequences only apply to literals in code, not to user input.